# For loop instead of while loop

Tags: jquery

Reading through the jQuery source I stumbled upon the following piece of code (available [here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.each)):

```
for (; i < length;) {
    if (callback.apply(object[i++], args) === false) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Why is a `for` loop used here instead of a `while` loop?

Comment: I wonder if this code is shorter when minimized? It's horrible code, and the jQuery guys are smart people, so I'd think it's for minification purposes.

Comment: Removing all whitespace, @aroth's version is shorter. Any variable name that can be shortened is used an equal number of times. Could get even shorter. `while(i<length&&callback.apply(object[i++],args)!==false);`

Comment: It could be argued that replacing all while loops with this form of for in the minified code compresses better.  No idea if that's what they had in mind, though.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I vote for someone having an affinity for bad coding style.  That's the only explanation I can see for both the `for` loop and the `i++` being placed inside of an array subscript.  I think this would be better:

```
while (i < length && callback.apply(object[i], args)) {
    i++;
}
```

Or if you happen to feel that the `===` operator in the original example has value, then:

```
while (i < length && callback.apply(object[i], args) !== false) {
    i++;
}
```

Another possible reason for doing this may have been as a performance optimization.  Although this quick [benchmark](http://jsbench.appspot.com/#suite=agdqc2JlbmNocg0LEgVTdWl0ZRjh1QYM) that I put together seems to disprove that theory.  On Windows the `while` loop above is 20% faster than the original `for` loop in Chrome, in IE and Firefox both loops perform the same.  On OS X the `for` loop has a 10% advantage in Firefox, there is no difference between the two in Chrome, and Safari prefers the `while` loop by 6%.

So from a performance standpoint it's a wash.  If anything then judging by market share you would probably want to optimize for Chrome on Windows before optimizing for Firefox on Mac, in which case the `while` loop would be preferred.

Which says to me that it's unlikely that performance optimization played a factor with this code.  And I return to my original theory that it's just an example of poor coding style making it past the code-review process.

Comment: The strict `false` test is necessary since that's the *one* return value that will break the iteration.

Comment: Wouldn't 'i' be out by 1 in your example?

Comment: The second version is required for equivalency to the original in cases where the callback could return `undefined` or `0`.  The first version would not work identically in those cases.

Comment: @AnteSim - No, because `i++` actually returns the value of 'i' [before the increment operation happens](http://blog.myrdo.com/2009/12/how-does-return-i-plus-plus-work/).  Which is why doing `array[i++]` should be avoided.  It's needlessly confusing.

Comment: Still, the code is not equivalent. If the loop breaks because the callback returns false, `i` will be one less here than in the original code.

Comment: @Jordi - The original code returns after the loop executes without making any additional reference to `i`, and `i` is scoped locally to the function.  So for all practical purposes they are the same.  There's no reason in this case to care about the value of `i` after the loop terminates.

Comment: I'd like to see the performance comparisons when faced with the task of iterating thousands of elements where an operation is performed at each iteration. Before you start criticizing, keep in mind that >24m websites are using jQuery and this is well understood and respected by those of us that are actually fixing jQuery bugs and contributing to the core. We _constantly_ review and nit pick code before it lands in the master branch, as well as bearing the burden of passing all >5k unit tests in browsers up to 10 years old. Pull Request if you think you can do better.

Comment: @Rick - Here's a [benchmark](http://jsbench.appspot.com/#suite=agdqc2JlbmNocg0LEgVTdWl0ZRjh1QYM).  I get no performance difference in Chrome, about 10% in favor of `for` in Firefox, and 6% in favor of `while` in Safari (using 20,000,000 iterations).  So really the performance issue is moot.  At best is shaves a few milliseconds off of 20 million iterations, and it's almost never worth obfuscating the code to do that.  But there's no need to get defensive.  I use and like jQuery.  But that doesn't mean its code is beyond reproach.  And no amount of popularity will make it so.

Comment: That was on my Mac at the office.  At home on my PC I get IE and Firefox showing no difference between `for` and `while`, and Chrome showing a 20% preference for the `while`.

Comment: @aroth, now that's what I'm talkin' about ;) raw numbers don't lie. Thanks for putting that together.

Answer (score 26):

Probably because it was "refactored" from a `for (x in obj)` loop: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.3.2&fn=jQuery.each

Answer (score 21):

Here is [the commit that introduced this oddity](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/eeab07179038a6a444e4b819f942663157768dfb).

Commit message:

> jquery core: code reduction at `$.each` and `$.curCSS`.

Snip from the diff:

```
-        for ( var i = 0, length = object.length; i < length; i++ )
-          if ( callback.apply( object[ i ], args ) === false )
+        for ( ; i < length; )
+          if ( callback.apply( object[ i++ ], args ) === false )
```

It would appear that the author simply missed the opportunity to change the `for` into a `while`.

Answer (score 6):

First, there is never a length cost for using a `for` loop over a `while` loop, but you get additional functionality with the `for` loop, so some coders just always use the `for`:

```
for(;<condition>;){}
while(<condition>){}
```

That said, I think the purpose here may be for consistency with the surrounding code.

For example, here is part of the original code.  As you can see, in this code you can stay in the "for" loop mode of thinking the whole time, so it *feels* more  consistent:

```
if (args) {
    if (isObj) {
        for (name in object) {
            if (callback.apply(object[name], args) === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (; i < length;) {
            if (callback.apply(object[i++], args) === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compare this to replacing the second loop with a `while`.  When you read this code, you have to switch from the "for" loop mode of thinking to the "while" loop mode of thinking.  Now I don't know about you, but I find it slightly faster for my eyes to switch between the loop conditions above as opposed to the loop conditions below.  This is because in the above case I can just concentrate on the conditions, whereas in the below case my eyes are drawn to reread the `while` and the `for` each time because they are different:

```
if (args) {
    if (isObj) {
        for (name in object) {
            if (callback.apply(object[name], args) === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        while (i < length) {
            if (callback.apply(object[i++], args) === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that things like this occur when I rewrite things or if multiple people touch a piece of code. Can't see any particular reason for it.

I hope ***i*** gets initialized properly above this block.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and most honest answer is pretty short "just because".
There is absolutely no practical reason to do it, we don't gain any profit from such 2-smiles loop.

As for aforementioned reasons, such as:

- refactoring - which is most possible, but nevertheless this is not an excuse.
- minification considerations - which is less, less possible.
- psychological/readability/code supporting issues - I very dubious that somebody write such code keeping in mind that a user can be confused for some code constructions and loose concentration;

well, as for these reasons - all of them definitely worth mentioning, but, to be honest, jquery code style is, well, not ideal. Sometimes there **are** reasons why it is so, some times, it's just a matter of fact.

Production code is not always the most beautiful code. Reading production-ready, hardcore code on any language is always for good, but is not 100% about code style. Say, vim is beautiful, very powerful software, but (as for me) some purist can be surprised with it source code. Though loops stuff is ok ))))

Answer (score 0):

So t will run at least once, because if you use a while loop if the logic is false it wont run. For lopp even if it is false it will run atleast once.